# Are there any references to the events of Guardians of the Galaxy 2 in other MCU titles?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

In Guardians of the Galaxy 2 . . .

> Ego reveals he planted pieces of him throughout the galaxy, including in Missouri on Earth. With Peter's help, he begins to activate them and these pieces of him start growing in giant blue blobs that consume everything. The exact timing of GotG2 isn't entirely clear, but given this was a serious (and extraterrestrial) event that occurred on American soil, I'm sure it would have gotten the attention of S.H.I.E.L.D., researchers like Erik Selvig or even the Avengers.

So given that, are there any references to it other MCU titles such as Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. or a tie-in comic?

Comment: I don't recall anything from Agents of SHIELD, except possibly the mysterious final scene of the season

Answer (score 4):

"Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2" is set in 2014, a few months after the first film.  The date is given at the start of the film when it opens with a flashback set in 1980 before jumping forward 34 years, which places it roughly between "Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D." seasons 1 & 2 (same as the first film); it would also be set between "Guardians of the Galaxy" and "Avengers: Age of Ultron".  Because GotGV2 wasn't made yet the creators of the show couldn't put references into the series.  It's possible that they'll work something in retroactively like they did with "Ant-Man".  The tie-in comic to the new film adapts the story of the first film.

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site. Have you checked out our [tour] and read [answer] yet? (Also, [ask] is good if you plan on asking any questions.) I hope you stick around!

Comment: Just curious, but what was the retroactive Ant-Man reference?