# Given the supposed time-line of GOTG Vol.2 why did Stan Lee claim to have been a Fed-Ex man?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, continuity, stan-lee

Perhaps an overly pedantic observation, however, in the *Guardians of the Galaxy* cameo Stan Lee claims to have been a Fed-Ex man. This is presumably a reference to the Stan Lee cameo at the end of *Captain America: Civil War*. In which Stan Lee is a Federal Express man who (humorously) calls Tony Stark "Tony Stank".

However, *Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol.2* is supposed to take place soon after the events of GOTG Vol.1, long before Civil War and thus before Stan Lee's character poses as a Fed-Ex man. So what's the deal here? Is time travel involved? Has Stan Lee been a Fed-Ex man twice?

Comment: "However GOTG Vol.2 is supposed to take place soon after the events of GOTG Vol.1 Long before Civil War..." Is it? Can you include a source for this in the question? Not that I doubt it, just haven't heard that before.

Comment: @Mwr247 - [Collider (referencing The MCU wiki)](http://collider.com/mcu-timeline-explained/#phase-three-infinity-war) places the events of GOTG1 in June 2014 and the events of GOTG2 in September 2014. Civil War takes place in and around May 2016.

Comment: @Mwr247, [answered here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/160439/5930).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

According to James Gunn, the writer/director of *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*, has provided an explanation for this in a Facebook Live session with fans:

> “I actually read the Marvel fan sites and the Marvel message boards out there and a lot of times people have ideas that are somewhat off-base or silly or whatever,” said Gunn. “But one thing I found very funny and interesting is the fact that people thought Stan Lee is a Watcher… and that all of these cameos that he’s doing are part of him being a Watcher. So I thought that was one of the greatest things the fans came up with.”
>
> “So, Stan Lee, as a guy who is either a Watcher – or probably a guy who is working for the Watchers – was something that I thought was fun for the MCU.
>
> “And yes, I know I made a mistake. People have written and asked me, and I'll own up to my mistake because Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2 theoretically happens in 2014 which is before [Captain America Civil War]. And Stan Lee in the movie says, ‘That time I was the Fed Ex guy,’ which is what he is in Civil War. I screwed up; I wasn't thinking. That’s all that is.”
>
> …
>
> “But I'm going to say that – probably – Stan Lee used the guise of a Fed Ex guy more than one time,” laughed Gunn. “So it’s a mistake, but it can easily be explained away!”
>
> Source: [IGN](http://www.ign.com/articles/2017/05/16/james-gunn-acknowledges-small-guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2-continuity-error)

Comment: +1 because more people on this site (and worldbuilders) need to realise how easy it is to explain away "problems" like this.

Comment: He could have also said that Stan Lee operates on a different timeline because he is from a transcendent reality with its own timeline. This has the advantage of being literally true.